# How to Pass Facebook User ID To Facebook Conversion API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, google-tag-manager

I use Google Tag Manager and sgtm to pass capi events to Facebook. But recently facebook showed a popup to pass the Facebook login id i.e. the user id of a Facebook user which is stored in a cookie hosted on the Facebook domain. As the cookie is hosted on the facebook domain GTM can't access the cookie value. Along with the Facebook Login ID facebook is asking to pass the external_id parameter with facebook events.

As there is no proper beginner-friendly documentation on how to pass these events, can you guys help me by sharing your idea's on how can i achieve this?

[image: This is a picture showing facebook telling to pass these parameters]

Comment: This is for when you are using Facebook Login on your site, so that you can get a user ID via API.

Comment: Is there a way i can get this value ?

Comment: Only if you implement Facebook Login. (_And_ people actually use it then.)

Comment: In my case majority of the people are from facebook mobile app. So will it be useful in my case and if yes how can i get this value ?

Comment: People would still explicitly have to log in to your site, using their username & password - because that doesn't "transfer" from the mobile app. So that would be a hassle for most mobile users already (who has their FB login credentials readily available, when they are using the mobile app?), plus - what for should they do it, if you don't offer _them_ any benefit? Also, I don't think Facebook lets you implement login for the general public any more, if you don't have a verified company.

Comment: so should i pass a random number i.e ga user id as external id and don't pass facebook login id ?

Comment: If you got nothing else ... (Not sure how much sense it makes to send an ID that was created _by_ Google in the first place, I would assume that probably already gets shared with the GTM code automatically in the background.)